# relative filepath for java

Tags: java, file, path

For my first java project I have been assigned to build a card flipping memory game that includes a leaderboard. In the project folder, there is the src folder, but there is also a folder named "resources". That is where the `leaderboard.txt` file is.

I have gotten everything working fine on my device, but the file path that I use to read in the leaderboard and write data to it is a local path: `C:\\Users\\Name\\Desktop\\ProjectFolder\\Resources\\Leaderboard.txt`. Obviously, this will not work on the instructor's computer.

How should I edit the file path so that it works on the grader's end? I have read something about using "/" as a separator but I don't know how I should incorporate that into the file path. I am using BufferedWriter and BufferedReader, so the code looks like this:

```
BufferedWriter scoreWrite = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\name\\Desktop\\CSCI\\MemoryGame\\resources\\leaderboard.txt"));
BufferedReader scoreRead = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\name\\Desktop\\CSCI\\MemoryGame\\resources\\leaderboard.txt"));
```

If MemoryGame is the folder created by cloning the repository and the resources folder is within the MemoryGame folder, would "./resources/leaderboard.txt" work as a filepath? The dot indicates that I am searching with a relative path, correct?

I am very new to Java so I would be very happy to receive any and all advice. Thank you all!

Comment: How are you reading the file? Please share your code.

Comment: I am using BufferedReader and BufferedWriter, so 

BufferedReader scoreReadStart = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\name\\Desktop\\CSCI\\MemoryGame\\resources\\leaderboard.txt")); 

and 

BufferedWriter scoreWrite = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\name\\Desktop\\CSCI\\MemoryGame\\resources\\leaderboard.txt"));

Comment: For future reference, please update your question with the relevant code instead of pasting it in the comments.

Comment: Understood, I have updated my question accordingly. Thank you for the tip.

Answer (score 2):

I personally prefer to use the Java NIO class [`Path`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html) in conjunction with [`Path#resolve(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#resolve-java.lang.String-), but if you're sticking with [`File`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html) you can use the [`File(File, String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File-java.io.File-java.lang.String-) constructor, which takes a parent argument.

Here's an example which assumes that the program's working directory is the same as the project's root directory:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    File workingDirectory = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
    System.out.println("The program is running in: " + workingDirectory);

    File resourcesDirectory = new File(workingDirectory, "resources");
    System.out.println("Resources directory: " + resourcesDirectory);

    File leaderboardFile = new File(resourcesDirectory, "leaderboard.txt");
    System.out.println("Leaderboard file: " + leaderboardFile);

    BufferedWriter scoreWrite = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(leaderboardFile));
    BufferedReader scoreRead = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(leaderboardFile));

    // ...
}
```

Unrelated to the question, but consider using a [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) statement.